# Htmlhost Control in Silverlight floating over the Silverlight header in the silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I developed one silver light application

I am using divtools:HtmlHost control for showing html content but when I scroll my page down the html content is floating over the silverlight header.

I set the z-index even though it's behaving the same..

Any one help me out from this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way to prevent that. Hosting HTML in Silverlight is a hack. All you can do is a work-around, re-think your application. Do you need the HTML to be in a Silverlight-managed scrollable area? If possible, place the HTML into a fixed area, where it can provide its own scrollable content.